# Suppressing Cancelled records in access vba generates an error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Im at wits end with my issue. I have a table that has positive and negative quantities. after splitting the two into separate tables i want to use the table with negative quantities to remove the first instance of the record from the table with positive quantities using vba. below is my code:

```
Public Sub Suppress_Offset()
Dim MYSQL As String
Dim MYSQL2 As String
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim rst2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Long
Dim db As DAO.Database

MYSQL2 = "select * From Negative where [QUANTITY]<0"

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(MYSQL2)

    If Not rst.EOF Then
        rst.MoveFirst
        Do Until rst.EOF
            MYSQL = ""
                MYSQL = MYSQL & "SELECT top 1 *" & vbCrLf
                MYSQL = MYSQL & "FROM Positive " & vbCrLf
                MYSQL = MYSQL & "Where [Unique ID] = "" & rst![Unique ID]) & "" [ACCOUNT #] = " & rst![ACCOUNT #] & " [MRN]= " & rst![MRN] & vbCrLf
                MYSQL = MYSQL & " [PATIENT NAME] = """ & CStr(rst![PATIENT NAME]) & vbCrLf
                MYSQL = MYSQL & " [CPT CODE]=""" & CStr(rst![CPT CODE]) & vbCrLf
                MYSQL = MYSQL & " [DATE OF SERVICE]=" & rst![DATE OF SERVICE] & vbCrLf
                MYSQL = MYSQL & " [ENTRY DATE] = " & rst![ENTRY DATE] & vbCrLf
                MYSQL = MYSQL & " [ATTENDING MD] =" & rst![ATTENDING MD] & vbCrLf
                MYSQL = MYSQL & " [ATTENDING MD NAME] = """ & CStr(rst![ATTENDING MD NAME]) & vbCrLf
                MYSQL = MYSQL & " [DISCHARGE FLOOR] = """ & CStr(rst![DISCHARGE FLOOR]) & vbCrLf
                MYSQL = MYSQL & " [DCFL DESC] = """ & CStr(rst![DCFL DESC]) & vbCrLf
                MYSQL = MYSQL & " [INOUT CODE] = """ & CStr(rst![INOUT CODE]) & vbCrLf
                MYSQL = MYSQL & " [FKEY] = """ & CStr(rst![FKEY]) & vbCrLf
                MYSQL = MYSQL & " [DISCHARGE DEPT] = """ & CStr(rst![DISCHARGE DEPT]) & vbCrLf
                MYSQL = MYSQL & " [DCDP DESC] = """ & CStr(rst![DCDP DESC]) & vbCrLf
                MYSQL = MYSQL & " [FAC/PRO] = """ & CStr(rst![FAC/PRO]) & vbCrLf
                MYSQL = MYSQL & " [QUANTITY]>0 and [QUANTITY]>= " & CStr(-rst![QUANTITY])

                Debug.Print TypeName(MYSQL), MYSQL

                Set rst2 = db.OpenRecordset(MYSQL)
                If Not rst2.EOF Then
                    rst2.Edit
                    rst2![QUANTITY] = rst2![QUANTITY] + rst![QUANTITY]
                    rst2.Update

                    rst.Edit
                    rst![QUANTITY] = 0
                    rst.Update
                End If
                rst2.Close
            rst.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
        rst.Close
End Sub
```

Can anyone see why i am getting a run time error 13 at: 
    Set rst2 = db.OpenRecordset(MYSQL)

please help! thanks

Output SQL:

```
String        SELECT top 1 *
FROM Positive 
Where [Unique ID] = " & rst![Unique ID]) & " [ACCOUNT #] = ########## [MRN]= #######
[PATIENT NAME] = "DOE, BANKSY
[CPT CODE]="#####
[DATE OF SERVICE]=########
[ENTRY DATE] = ########
[ATTENDING MD] =XXXX
[ATTENDING MD NAME] = "BACON, KEVIN
[DISCHARGE FLOOR] = "XXXX
[DCFL DESC] = "RESEARCH/DEVELOPMENT
[INOUT CODE] = "X
[FKEY] = "X-XXXXXXXXXXX
[DISCHARGE DEPT] = "XXXX
[DCDP DESC] = "XXXXXXXX
[FAC/PRO] = "X
[QUANTITY]>0 and [QUANTITY]>= 1
String        SELECT top 1 *
FROM Positive 
Where [Unique ID] = " & rst![Unique ID]) & " [ACCOUNT #] = ########## [MRN]= #######
[PATIENT NAME] = "DOE, BANKSY
[CPT CODE]="#####
[DATE OF SERVICE]=########
[ENTRY DATE] = ########
[ATTENDING MD] =XXXX
[ATTENDING MD NAME] = "BACON, KEVIN
[DISCHARGE FLOOR] = "XXXX
[DCFL DESC] = "RESEARCH/DEVELOPMENT
[INOUT CODE] = "X
[FKEY] = "X-XXXXXXXXXXX
[DISCHARGE DEPT] = "XXXX
[DCDP DESC] = "XXXXXXXX
[FAC/PRO] = "X
[QUANTITY]>0 and [QUANTITY]>= 1
```

Comment: Splitting a table into one for negative values and another for positive values seems odd.  Why do that?

Comment: because whenever i try to use the aggregate totals function in the query the results get sketchy. If you have any suggestions on how to fix that it would also be greatly appreciated

Comment: My db instincts made me question splitting one table into 2.  But I can't claim it's the wrong way for your specific situation.  You could submit a question to show us why the single-table results are sketchy.  If it's fixable with just the one table, I suspect someone here can show you a better way.

Comment: Actually can anyone come up with VBA to help me cancel out the negative records for just one table? I am noticing integrity issues with the two separate tables now as well. Thanks

Comment: Can you use a query to select only non-negative records?

Comment: I cant completely discard the negatives as I need their quantities to be summed up to figure out which charges are really there as opposed to the charges that were credited back to the account

Comment: Thank you Tom Collins and HansUp for your help. I tried the suggestions and received this error: 3075. Missing operator for query in syntax expression. How do i fix this? I edited my submission above to show my new code.

Comment: Please show us the output from `Debug.Print MYSQL` ... that should make it easier to spot the SQL syntax problem.

Comment: The output SQL is broken.  It looks like 2 copies of one `SELECT` statement, but that statement won't work by itself either.  Can you create a valid `SELECT` query in the query designer which returns the result set you need?

Comment: no, not without finding some errors. i tried to do a select query with an aggregate sum at the quantity field but it kept missing records to properly sum. Any way around that?

Comment: I meant create an Access query which corresponds to what you need for `MYSQL` the first time through the loop.  Use static values instead of  values from the other recordset (such as `rst![Unique ID]`).  That effort should allow you to create valid Access SQL.  Once you have that SQL, recreate it with your VBA code and use the values from the other recordset in place of the static values.  I don't have any idea about the aggregate query you mentioned now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine the content of `MYSQL` immediately before the code attempts to use it with `OpenRecordset`.

```vb
Debug.Print TypeName(MYSQL), MYSQL
Set rst2 = db.OpenRecordset(MYSQL)
```

You can see the `Debug.Print` output in the Immediate window; go there with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>

My hunch is that `MYSQL` doesn't contain what you expect.  Based on the way that variable is built, it could even be Null instead of a string.

The reason it could be Null is because `MYSQL` is declared like this:

```vb
Dim MYSQL, MYSQL2 As String
```

You might expect both variables will be declared `AS String`.  However, only `MYSQL2` is String.  `MYSQL` is Variant.  So that declaration has the same effect as this:

```vb
Dim MYSQL As Variant, MYSQL2 As String
```

Since `MYSQL` is intended to hold a SQL statement, declare it `AS String` which will not allow it to contain Null.

```vb
Dim MYSQL As String, MYSQL2 As String
```

Notice you have a similar issue when you declare the recordset variables.

```vb
Dim rst, rst2 As DAO.Recordset ' rst will be Variant
```

However, I don't think that declaration contributes to the immediate problem.  Something like can cause unwelcome surprises in other contexts, though.

Comment: Please also follow Tom's suggestions for building the `MYSQL` string correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell from your code, but here's a few suggestions.

- Do not use the + for concatenations. The correct operator is the &. + will often work, but sometimes it likes to add instead.
- If the field is not a string, don't convert your variable to a string and wrap it in quotes. Leave it as is.
- Having a super long line of code makes it harder to edit later or to debug. Break it up. Something like this maybe:

  var1 = ""
  var1 = var1 & "SELECT * " & vbCrLf
  var1 = var1 & "FROM   orders " & vbCrLf
  var1 = var1 & "WHERE  shipcity = "" & me!txtshipcity  & "" "

Strings can also be quoted with single quotes. This is easier sometimes.

Follow these steps and I bet you find your error.